# Show that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the only solution for the system $\left\{\begin{array}{l}{a x+b y=0} \\ {c x+d y=0}\end{array}\right.$ iff $a d-b c \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

It's obvious that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a solution. I have to show that it's the only solution iff $ad-bc \neq 0$.

I can't see what $a d-b c \neq 0$ has to do with anything. Also, I'm not sure whether $a,b,c,d$ are arbitary real numbers or what. I tried to play with it

$$ ad\neq bc \iff \frac{a}{b}\neq \frac{c}{d}, \quad \text{$b,d\neq0$, so that's why I'm allowed to divide by them}$$

This must mean that the system is not trivial. By this I mean that the to equation can't be transformed to one another.

**idea 2** (I'm note sure what idea 1 was)

Prove the equivalence

$$ \text{$(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the only solution} \iff ad-bc \neq0$$

- by first prove the implikation from left to right: $\implies$
- the prove from right to left: $\Longleftarrow$

I'm I right or wrong?

Is idea 2 good enough?

PS just started LA

Comment: A general idea to show that something is unique is to show if there existed another solution $(x',y')$ besides $(x,y)$ than this implies $x=x' $ and  $y'=y$

Comment: @XPenguen Have you succeed in using that idea? I could not make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ad-bc\ne 0$ then try to solve your system by elimination method.

Multiply the first equation by $-c$ and the second one by $a$ and add the to get $$(ad-bc)y=0$$

Since $ad-bc\ne 0$ we have to have $y=0$

Similarly you get  $x=0$

The same goes for if $y\ne 0$ and  $$(ad-bc)y=0$$then we have to have   $ad-bc= 0$

Comment: How does this show the equivalence?

Comment: @Xenusi  It show the idea behind the proof.

Comment: I get it now. Had to sleep on it.