# Show that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the only solution to the system of equations $ax+by=0$, $cx+dy=0$ iff. $ad-bc \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

**I'm learning Linear Algebra and I can't figure out this problem:**

Show that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the only solution to the system of equations
$$
ax+by=0
$$
$$
cx+dy=0
$$
if and only if $ad-bc \neq 0$

**So far we've studied systems of equations and rank of matrices.**

Comment: hint: What happens if you gausian elimination on the matrix ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437317/show-that-x-y-0-0-is-the-only-solution-for-the-system-left-beginarray?rq=1

Comment: another hint: $ad - bc$ is the determinant of the coefficient matrix.

Answer (score 0):

First notice that $ax + by = 0$ and $cx + dy= 0$ is the same as the matrix
$M := \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}$=
$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix}
$

"$\Leftarrow$" This direction is easy. If $ad-bc \neq 0$ then the matrix $M$ has an inverse. Consequently
$M^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y 
\end{pmatrix}
$
So $x,y=0$.

"$\Rightarrow$" For this direction you can do what Brad S. recommended in the comments. Simple use gaussian elimination (i.e. solving for x,y).

Answer (score 0):

These are two lines passing through origin their slopes are $m_1=-a/b$ and $m_2=-c/d$
if the slopes are equal $(m_1=m_2)$ then $ad-bc=0$, both lines are coincident and there are infinitely mny solutions.

If slopes are unequal $(m_1\ne m_1 \implies ad-bc\ne 0$) they will meet only in the origin $(0,0)$.